# python script works but heroku crashs

Tags: python, heroku, beautifulsoup, sendgrid

I am building an app for my dad which scraps the lotto results (beautifulsoup) and send them via email (sendgrid). I use heroku to run the script [github repo](https://github.com/algore87/lotto-mailer) on a scheduled basis. If I run it, it will work fine. The emails will be sent but the process crash's which restarts them because of the [dyno restart policy](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/344). The crash isn't that bad because the script will do its job but the problem is the restart of the dyno, which leads to many emails sent. You will find the script in my repo.

My guess is the asynchronicity with beautiful soup and/or sendgrid. Do you know how to get better log information in heroku? If I comment out the actual email sending part and start the scheduler on ten minutes then it works but the worker doesn't.

My Procfile looks like:

```
worker: python lotto_mailer.py
```

Here is the server log.

```
Nov 19 05:56:36 lotto-mailer heroku/scheduler.2285: Starting process with command `if [ "$(date +%u)" = 1 ]; then python lotto_mailer.py; fi` 
Nov 19 05:56:37 lotto-mailer heroku/scheduler.2285: State changed from starting to up 
Nov 19 05:56:40 lotto-mailer heroku/scheduler.2285: State changed from up to complete 
Nov 19 05:56:40 lotto-mailer heroku/scheduler.2285: Process exited with status 0 
Nov 19 05:56:41 lotto-mailer app/scheduler.2285: Ziehung vom Samstag, 17.11.2018 
Nov 19 05:56:41 lotto-mailer app/scheduler.2285: Gewinnzahlen: [3, 6, 18, 31, 39, 40] SZ: 5 
... App OUTPUT ...
Nov 19 05:56:41 lotto-mailer app/scheduler.2285: UTC Hour: 13
```

Don't get distracted by the command which the scheduler runs. It's just to run it only on mondays. It seems that only the worker crashs not the scheduler.

```
Nov 19 06:04:24 lotto-mailer heroku/worker.1: State changed from crashed to starting 
Nov 19 06:04:29 lotto-mailer heroku/worker.1: Starting process with command `python lotto_mailer.py` 
Nov 19 06:04:29 lotto-mailer heroku/worker.1: State changed from starting to up 
Nov 19 06:04:29 lotto-mailer heroku/worker.1: State changed from crashed to starting 
Nov 19 06:04:32 lotto-mailer heroku/worker.1: State changed from up to crashed 
Nov 19 06:04:33 lotto-mailer heroku/worker.1: Process exited with status 0 
Nov 19 06:04:33 lotto-mailer app/worker.1: Ziehung vom Samstag, 17.11.2018 
Nov 19 06:04:33 lotto-mailer app/worker.1: Gewinnzahlen: [3, 6, 18, 31, 39, 40] SZ: 5
... APP  OUTPUT ...
```

Why does the worker run at all? If you need further information, just let me now. Thank you for your help.

***solution:*** I have recognized that I can deactivate the worker 
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHSUe.jpg)
and just let the scheduler run but the question remains, why does the worker crash.

Answer (score 2):

worker is for web service/server not CLI app this is why it crash and you receive many email because it will auto restart if crash. worker is not required you can delete `Procfile` or maybe create dummy server that actually scheduler using `while` and `sleep`.